# Use git to manage home directory

Tags: git

I'd like to create **one single git repo** in my Linux $HOME directory. In this repo - obviously - I could add everything under version control, but this wouldn't make any sense. I'd like to only add the files and folders that are relevant to me, like *.vimrc*, *.vim*, *.bashrc*, etc. (probably only hidden files and folders, but maybe not)

I know I could leverage *.gitignore* to try and achieve such behavior but that would be painful and virtually un-maintainable. Instead, what I'd want to know is if there'd be any way to manually declare files and folders that I would want to manage, and only that.

Comment: You mean something like [dotfiles](http://blog.smalleycreative.com/tutorials/using-git-and-github-to-manage-your-dotfiles/)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adding your .vim ~/.vimrc to github (aka dot files)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18197705/adding-your-vim-vimrc-to-github-aka-dot-files)

Answer (score 54, accepted):

**.gitignore**

```
# Ignore everything
*

# But not these files...
!*.vimrc
!*.vim
!*.bashrc
!.gitignore

# etc...
```

My home directory is also on [GitHub](https://github.com/vanniktech/config-home).

Comment: Would the new `.git` dir. created by `git init` conflict with any of the existing user-specific config. typically found in the home dir.?

Comment: I know it's what the op asked, but I personally don't like this approach. You will never be automatically warned if something new appears in your home directory. Ideally you just decide once for everything in there whether to ignore it or keep it. I'm trying right now with a clean debian install, but admittedly there is already quite some cruft in there. A good sample .gitignore file for /home would be a great resource cause anything new should be new software you install, in which case I at least want to see it appear and decide whether I want it's configuration in my vcs.

Comment: The advantage being, if I reinstall or migrate etc I can add the old repo as a remote, and then get all my configs for all my software and merge in what I want. Not just .bashrc and a few other things.

Comment: This is great but not if you have other Git modules in your home directory.

Comment: @user1115652's point is a valid argument against this. However, we can use `git clean -nxd .[^.]*` to list all of the files ignored by the `.gitignore`. This is a fun substitute to list all _untracked_ files in our home directory since everything is ignored by the `*` rule, allowing us to find any potential extra configuration files we might want to track in the Git repo. We can also use `git check-ignore` to check if a file is ignored, but this behaves a bit differently than a `git clean` dry run.

Comment: To @JaredBeck's point, getting this repo onto another machine is not as straightforward and cloning into our home repo as it will almost always be non-empty and will already have files conflicting with our remote. The approach I've taken on new machines is the following: `git init; git remote add origin ...; git fetch origin master; git reset --hard origin/master`. The hard reset will remove any conflicting files.

Comment: Two days later, I think `git status --ignored` is actually the best way to check for anything new that pops up in our home directory.

Comment: This is really nice but I found it was better to use put these rules in `~/.git/info/exclude` instead of `~/.gitignore` so that search tools like `rg` do not ignore everything.

Answer (score 38):

I would setup an alias for use only with your home repo
this way you can use the alias in place of git command and you always know the context you are working in

```
# .bashrc
alias home='git --work-tree=$HOME --git-dir=$HOME/.home'
```

Issuing the comand

```
$ home init
```

will create a repo in .home folder in your $HOME and irrelevant of current directory you can work with your home repo with the alias 'home' in place of 'git'

This alongside a .gitignore should be all you need.

```
# .gitignore
*
# keep track
!.bashrc
!.gitignore
```

NB. DO NOT KEEP .ssh/keys in repo as it presents file permission and security issues.

Comment: This is a fantastic solution; thank you!  My only change would be to not use `.gitignore` but instead use `$GIT_DIR/info/exclude` (so, `$HOME/.home/info/exclude`).  I also prefer `$HOME/.home.git` or such, but this is superfluous mostly, with this alias at hand.

Comment: Just curious, if I implemented this solution on machine A and cloned the repo on machine B, would git overwrite existing files in the home directory on B?

Comment: [A blog about this technique](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/dotfiles).  A related [HN thread](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=11070797).

Comment: This technique is incompatible with any git tools like Fork/GitKraken/Sourcetree. If you're happy with git CLI - great! If not... you'll either need to get over it or use a different technique. (Your tool _might_ support a custom `work-tree` and `git-dir` e.g. [Magit](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/30602/use-nonstandard-git-directory-with-magit), but you'll need to research/do it yourself.)

Answer (score 23):

I would suggest *not* putting your $HOME directory under git version control.  I did this, because I thought I was exceedingly clever and wanted my .dotfiles under version control.  However, git is greedy and ravenous.  I had to add tons of directories (or even *) to my $HOME/.gitignore.  And do you have any git repositories elsewhere in your home directory?  I did.  But those git repositories will use your $HOME/.gitignore as your global .gitignore unless you set that elsewhere.  So it's a real pain to try and add files in these sub-directory repositories.

Instead, put your important files in a separate directory.  Say, ~/dotfiles.  Now make that a git repository, and symlink all of your important .dotfiles to point at that new repository.  Voila.  Problem solved, albeit with some time invested in linking.

Comment: Imagine forgetting you're in `~` and doing a `git clean -xdf`.  (I do this on a regular basis in other repos to get it back to a clean state. Obviously the effects in `~` would be _disastrous_.) On a separate note, [chezmoi](https://www.chezmoi.io/) automates the symlinking if you set its config to `mode = "symlink"`

Answer (score 11):

I think you're looking for [dotfiles](http://dotfiles.github.io/).

Comment: Going with the .gitignore file seems to better fit my use case for now, but thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way is to set up a git repository in somewhere else (preferably in physically different disk) and adding your files in it.
You can creat empty git repo using doing
(at a safe file system, preferably different disk, like /home1)

```
sudo git init --bare mynewrepos.git
sudo chown -fR myself mynewrepos.git
sudo chgrp -fR myself mynewrepos.git
```

now, go to your home directory, and do

```
git clone /home1/mynewrepos.git   # now you are cloning from empty git repos.
```

then add your precious files to the git (git add, git commit, git push .. and all). I didn't try it for keeping my usual files under my home, but I use this method to manage my local project files (before uploading to official git repos.). But again, if you have many git managed files under your home, they might be affected by your .gitignorefiles under your home.