# How can I disallow git commands from moving to the parent directory?

Tags: git

I have a git repository of my dot-files in my home directory.
Every time I use a git command (e.g. `git log`) in a subdirectory, which doesn't have it's own repo, I'm getting the log of the dot files repo, e.g.

```
/home/dimid     $ cd foo
/home/dimid/foo $ git status

... log of ~/.git
```

However, I would like to confine my dot-repository only to files and directories that begin with a dot (e.g. `.vim`), such that when I'm in `~/foo` and `~/foo/.git` doesn't exist `git log` will output the usual

```
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
```

even though that the parent directory `~` contains a `.git` folder.

I thought about aliasing `git` and add an exception, is there a more elegant way?

Comment: I'm afraid that's quite difficult to obtain; if not impossible. Git is made to go up directories to check if the current directory is part of a git repo; and since your home directory is one...

Comment: Rather than searching for how to make Git ignore subdirectories, perhaps you should be searching for how to properly keep files like your .vimrc in source control.

Comment: @tom I'd love to hear suggestions

Comment: @dimid here's someone's response to the exact same root problem http://stackoverflow.com/a/18197818/1394473

Answer (score 3):

I don't know any way of doing that; since Git always moves up your directory tree until he finds a `.git` directory. Now since your `/home` directory is a git repository; all sub-directories will always find that `.git` directory in your `/home` folder.

I can see one work-around, but it isn't very clean...

- create a subdirectory in your home (or elsewhere); where you will initialize your git repository (eg "/home/user/configfiles/")
- now create hardlinks between your configfiles you want to keep in your git repository and the ones on your system (eg "ln ~/.config ./") (**note** you need to use hardlinks; otherwise git will only version the path where the symbolic link is pointing to)

This way your home directory will not be a git repository anymore; and the problem is avoided...

Comment: Thanks, but `~` has some submodules (like `.vim/bundle`) so I'd rather not having to track them dynamically and add hardlinks

Comment: I know it isn't the most beautiful solution... But you had to do 'git add' for each file anyway?

Comment: I agree that this solution isn't very beautifull (as I said in the answer). It does have quite some flaws; but it's the best I could come up with...

Comment: Thanks, I upvoted your answer. If no better alternative comes up, I'll accept it or try the alias trick.

Comment: tx. It is a valid question; I'd be interested too if I hear any other suggestions :)