# How do I make my plugins work with `set encoding=utf-8` in Vim run from Windows PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, vim, encoding

## What I want

I want to use the a plugin for Vim and I use the famous plugin manager pathogen for this (https://github.com/tpope/vim-pathogen).

The plugin is `vim-ps1` (https://github.com/PProvost/vim-ps1) and provides syntax coloring for Windows Powershell files whose file extension is `*.ps1`.

## My config

In order to install my plugin, I just cloned it into the bundle directory. I'm on my office computer which runs Windows, so my `vimfiles` directory (instead of the `.vim` linux version) looks like this:

```
    vimfiles
     ├── autoload
     │    └── pathogen.vim
     ├── bundle
     │    ├── nerdtree
     │    └── vim-ps1
     ├── spell
     ├── template
     └── vimrc
```

So there are two plugins, `vim-ps1` which I want to install, and nerdtree, added there only to be sure my problems aren't from the plugin (I made the assumption that there is particular problem with `nerdtree`).

The `vimrc` file is loaded by the `_vimrc` file because I want to version my settings. More information about this here https://stackoverflow.com/a/18203545/7964523

```
    runtime vimrc
```

## The problem

### With `set encoding=utf-8`, I can't use plugins

When I open a `*.sp1` nothing happens. Here is the content of my `vimrc` file for the debugging:

```
    runtime! debian.vim
    set nocompatible

    execute pathogen#infect("~/vimfiles/bundle/{}")
    syntax on
    filetype plugin indent on

    set encoding=utf-8
```

The output of `:scriptnames` is

```
      1: ~\_vimrc
      2: ~\vimfiles\vimrc
      3: ~\vimfiles\autoload\pathogen.vim
      4: C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim81\syntax\syntax.vim
      5: C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim81\syntax\synload.vim
      6: C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim81\syntax\syncolor.vim
      7: C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim81\filetype.vim
      8: ~\vimfiles\bundle\vim-ps1\ftdetect\ps1.vim
      9: ~\vimfiles\bundle\vim-ps1\ftdetect\ps1xml.vim
     10: ~\vimfiles\bundle\vim-ps1\ftdetect\xml.vim
     11: C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim81\ftplugin.vim
     12: C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim81\indent.vim
     13: C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim81\plugin\getscriptPlugin.vim
     14: C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim81\plugin\gzip.vim
     15: C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim81\plugin\logiPat.vim
     16: C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim81\plugin\manpager.vim
     17: C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim81\plugin\matchparen.vim
     18: C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim81\plugin\netrwPlugin.vim
     19: C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim81\plugin\rrhelper.vim
     20: C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim81\plugin\spellfile.vim
     21: C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim81\plugin\tarPlugin.vim
     22: C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim81\plugin\tohtml.vim
     23: C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim81\plugin\vimballPlugin.vim
     24: C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim81\plugin\zipPlugin.vim
     25: C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim81\scripts.vim
     26: C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim81\syntax\vim.vim
     27: C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim81\ftplugin\vim.vim
     28: C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim81\indent\vim.vim
```

You can see that there are some files from the `vim-ps1` directory loaded. The output of `":set runtimepath?` is

```
    runtimepath=
    ~\vimfiles\bundle\nerdtree,
    ~\vimfiles\bundle\vim-ps1,
    ~/vimfiles,
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim/vimfiles,
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim81,
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim/vimfiles/after,
    ~/vimfiles/after
```

You can also see that `nerdtree` and `vim-sp1` folders are there, but none of them works.

### Without `set encoding=utf-8`, I have trouble with characters display

Now I remove the line `set encoding=utf-8` from my `vimrc`file. I open the `*.sp1`, and the syntax coloring feature works! Nerdtree works too.

But I now have trouble with the display of some characters, like the character code `ac` (checked with the vim command `ga`) interpreted as `¬` in utf-8 and `¼` in latin-1.

The output of `:scriptnames` provides more lines including those related to the syntax plugin (see 46, 47, 48):

```
      1: ~\_vimrc
      2: ~\vimfiles\vimrc
      3: ~\vimfiles\autoload\pathogen.vim
      4: C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim81\syntax\syntax.vim
      5: C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim81\syntax\synload.vim
      6: C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim81\syntax\syncolor.vim
      7: C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim81\filetype.vim
      8: ~\vimfiles\bundle\vim-ps1\ftdetect\ps1.vim
      9: ~\vimfiles\bundle\vim-ps1\ftdetect\ps1xml.vim
     10: ~\vimfiles\bundle\vim-ps1\ftdetect\xml.vim
     11: C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim81\ftplugin.vim
     12: C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim81\indent.vim
     13: ~\vimfiles\bundle\nerdtree\plugin\NERD_tree.vim
     14: ~\vimfiles\bundle\nerdtree\autoload\nerdtree.vim
     15: ~\vimfiles\bundle\nerdtree\lib\nerdtree\path.vim
     16: ~\vimfiles\bundle\nerdtree\lib\nerdtree\menu_controller.vim
     17: ~\vimfiles\bundle\nerdtree\lib\nerdtree\menu_item.vim
     18: ~\vimfiles\bundle\nerdtree\lib\nerdtree\key_map.vim
     19: ~\vimfiles\bundle\nerdtree\lib\nerdtree\bookmark.vim
     20: ~\vimfiles\bundle\nerdtree\lib\nerdtree\tree_file_node.vim
     21: ~\vimfiles\bundle\nerdtree\lib\nerdtree\tree_dir_node.vim
     22: ~\vimfiles\bundle\nerdtree\lib\nerdtree\opener.vim
     23: ~\vimfiles\bundle\nerdtree\lib\nerdtree\creator.vim
     24: ~\vimfiles\bundle\nerdtree\lib\nerdtree\flag_set.vim
     25: ~\vimfiles\bundle\nerdtree\lib\nerdtree\nerdtree.vim
     26: ~\vimfiles\bundle\nerdtree\lib\nerdtree\ui.vim
     27: ~\vimfiles\bundle\nerdtree\lib\nerdtree\event.vim
     28: ~\vimfiles\bundle\nerdtree\lib\nerdtree\notifier.vim
     29: ~\vimfiles\bundle\nerdtree\autoload\nerdtree\ui_glue.vim
     30: ~\vimfiles\bundle\nerdtree\nerdtree_plugin\exec_menuitem.vim
     31: ~\vimfiles\bundle\nerdtree\nerdtree_plugin\fs_menu.vim
     32: ~\vimfiles\bundle\nerdtree\nerdtree_plugin\vcs.vim
     33: C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim81\plugin\getscriptPlugin.vim
     34: C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim81\plugin\gzip.vim
     35: C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim81\plugin\logiPat.vim
     36: C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim81\plugin\manpager.vim
     37: C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim81\plugin\matchparen.vim
     38: C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim81\plugin\netrwPlugin.vim
     39: C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim81\plugin\rrhelper.vim
     40: C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim81\plugin\spellfile.vim
     41: C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim81\plugin\tarPlugin.vim
     42: C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim81\plugin\tohtml.vim
     43: C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim81\plugin\vimballPlugin.vim
     44: C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim81\plugin\zipPlugin.vim
     45: C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim81\scripts.vim
     46: ~\vimfiles\bundle\vim-ps1\syntax\ps1.vim
     47: ~\vimfiles\bundle\vim-ps1\ftplugin\ps1.vim
     48: ~\vimfiles\bundle\vim-ps1\indent\ps1.vim
```

No change of the output of `:set runtimepath?`

## What I  try to overcome this

I manage to identify the trigger (see above).

I moved the line `set encoding=utf-8`

- the problem remains the same whatever its position after the line that executes pathogen
- above the line that executes pathogen, I got this error:

  ```
  E117: Unknown function: pathogen#infect
  E15: Invalid expression: pathogen#infect("~/vimfiles/bundle/{}")
  ```

so it is worst.

## How do I make my plugins work with `set encoding=utf-8`?

## Edit1

As I'm running Vim 8.1, I applied the solution suggested by @Matt. The problem is still here but is not linked to pathogen.

Adding `set fileencodings=utf-8,default` changed nothing.

I ran from my terminal `vim -Vdebug` and analysed the output file `debug`. My user name contains the letter `é` coded `e9` in hexadecimal unicode, and at some point in the debugging file I've got

```
    Searching for "C:\Users\Aur<e9>lien/vimfiles/pack/*/start/*"
```

See the `<e9>` part. It is four separate characters `<`, `e`, `9` and `>` (I can put my cursor over each of them).

Without `set fileencodings=utf-8,default` and `set encoding=utf-8`, the output of the debugging file is correct (except the slashes and backslashes but it works):

```
    Searching for "C:\Users\Aurélien/vimfiles/pack/*/start/*"
```

This explains why it doesn't work with `set encoding=utf-8`, but I can't explain this behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to modify a parameter in Windows in order to use UTF-8 properly. It is under "Control Panel" > "Clock and Region" > "Region". Under the Tab "Administrative", click on "Change system locale...". You need to have administrator privileges for this.

Change setting part 1:
[image: Change setting part 1]

Then check the box before "Beta: Use Unicode UTF-8 for worldwide language support" (see the screenshot below).

Change setting part 2:
[image: Change setting part 2]

I don't know exactly what this parameter changes. There is actually a question about it on Stack Overflow: [What does "Beta: Use Unicode UTF-8 for worldwide language support" actually do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56419639/what-does-beta-use-unicode-utf-8-for-worldwide-language-support-actually-do). It does not have any answers yet.

An older thread on Microsoft forum does not provide more information: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/6f9f1695-9d64-43f3-8527-6b895599233a/use-unicode-utf8-for-worldwide-language-support

Answer (score 0):

Look like you're running Vim 8, so you don't need Pathogen at all. Just move your plugins under `~/vimfiles/pack/bundle/start` and you're done. Read `:help packages` for more info.

Also, in my experience setting `set encoding=utf-8` as **the very first line** (not counting comments) in your config saves many troubles.

Comment: I actually didn't know this possibility to use plugins. I tried your solution, removing the line executing pathogen and setting my folders correctly. The problem remains. 

With `set encoding=utf-8` at the very first line (or positioned as presented in the question), plugins are not loaded though `:set runtimepath?` returns `~\vimfiles\pack\bundle\start\vim-ps1` and `~\vimfiles\pack\bundle\start\nerdtree`.
Without `set encoding=utf-8`, plugins are loaded but I have characters display problems.

Comment: @quelinau Add `set fileencodings=utf-8,default`

Comment: Thanks for helping me. I did that but it changed nothing. After more research, it appears that the problem comes from the interaction with the terminal I use: Windows PowerShell. I updated the original post, see "Edit1"

Comment: @quelinau Powershell doesn't have a terminal of its own, so it's standard conhost which never supported utf-8 properly (btw. if you're on Win10 you may try to upgrade to that fancy [new experimental terminal](https://github.com/microsoft/Terminal)). So it is very daring of you to use non-ASCII symbols in system directories names. But I don't think that Git for Windows (msys/mintty I assume?) is a practical decision, and suggest to give a try to gvim instead.

Comment: @quelinau BTW. Here on SO the OP is encouraged to write his own solution as an answer and to accept it, rather than to add it to the question.

Comment: Same problem with gVim. And I always use ascii characters for my files and directories names. It is just the default behavior of Windows which asks your name when you create a user and use it as you gave it for the home directory name. And it seems that there is no easy way to change it on Windows 10. See https://superuser.com/questions/890812/how-to-rename-the-user-folder-in-windows-10 for example. I don't have trouble with linux. I added the answer but I'll accept one which uses PowerShell.

Comment: @quelinau I can't reproduce this issue, so I'm not sure what is the best way to deal with it, but you can try simply to add to vimrc `let $HOME='C:/Users/Aurélien'` (in utf-8) and see if it works for you.

Comment: @quelinau There's also recommended `scriptencoding utf-8` setting.

Comment: I tried `let $HOME='C:/Users/Aurélien'` and `scriptencoding utf-8`, but it still doesn't work. I eventually found the solution: changing the parameter "Use Unicode UTF-8 for worldwide language support". Thank you for your help @Matt.

Answer (score 0):

**I found a solution**: running Vim from a different terminal than Windows Powershell. The terminal I used for this is the one that ships with Git for Windows (https://gitforwindows.org/). As @Matt mentioned, it is based on mintty.

Changing the code page of Windows PowerShell from the default 850 (latin-1) to 65001 (utf-8) has no effect. I don't have to use Windows PowerShell, but another solution would be helpful for people who need to.

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with this problem, too (my USERNAME & USERPROFILE contain a Unicode letter). For me the following worked:

```
set encoding=utf-8
set fileencoding=utf-8
set termencoding=utf-8

let &runtimepath = '~/vimfiles,' . &runtimepath

" the rest of the script
```